# How to add an external dependency to an eclipse project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am familiar with importing JAR dependencies to android project from

Project > Build path > Add external archives

But I dont know how to import dependencies like this ([sample from google firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)):

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
}
```

Is this example instruction leads to a JAR file or what? How should I import dependencies like this to an android project?

Answer (score 2):

Import android library project as module in your current app. than add the project name in **build.gradle(module:app)** file  like this-> **compile project(':lib')** suppose the importing project name is lib.

Comment: What do you mean from android library project ? e.g.what is the android library project for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0 ?

Comment: if u working on eclipse IDE than I am sorry, I just gave u an example to add an external project as module/ library at your current project in android studio

Answer (score 1):

Please find the `build.gradle` file in your project. It is mostly located in the 'root' unless you have set a custom location.

Then in build.gradle, add the above code snippet that you have shared.
If your gradle file already had a **dependencies{}** node, just copy past the **complie** part of the above code in your **dependencies**.

If not, then paste it as it is.

Goodluck.

Comment: I can not find build.gradle in my project. This is an android project. Should I convert it to anything else?